# Matlab keep loading old excel sheet

Tags: excel, matlab, matlab-deployment

I am facing this annoying problem in matlab. I tried to open excel sheet and read the specific column in matlab but matlab keep on reading the old excel file. I have even changed the path of the sheet but still problem persists. The file names are same but the are in different folders. each time when I have to read a file  I give a file path. The code I am using is this.

```
srcdir = 'path to the file'; 
srcfiles = dir(fullfile(srcdir, 'name.xls')); 
a= xlsread('sheetname','B:B');
```

Do anybody knows about this problem?

Comment: Have you closed and reopened the matlab instance?

Comment: You need to add far more detail to make this problem reproducible...

Comment: @RGA yes I even tried that.

Comment: @Dan sorry I didnt understand

Comment: @durasm I even changed the file names

Comment: @Ahsan it is impossible given the information provided, for anyone to reproduce your problem. If we can't reproduce then we can't solve it beyond saying have you tried turning your computer off and on again...

Comment: @Dan I restarted my computer. It seems like the values in that varaible are fixed from old excel file. Although in the same script its is reading another file and reading the data from that excel file correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the path relative to the dir of the .m and add that as first argument in xlsread

```
A=xlsread('pathA/Name.xlsx','sheetname','B:B');
B=xlsread('pathB/Name.xlsx','sheetname','B:B');
```